# Hover circle trigger doesn't work on more than one circle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I found this tutorial and started to add on to it by changing the html etc.

When I add in another circle the first one still works but when I hover over the second circle it does nothing..

I am planning on having 4 circles all at different sizes and when you click on them they reveal the data/ information inside.

Here is a link to a [DEMO](http://dev.zackreid.com/bird/js/index.html) which shows what is going wrong. I might even need the small ones to get bigger to give more space for the data to appear.

**Edit**

Forgot to add code, here is the css:

```
    .section{
    width: 900px;
    height: 420px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    position: relative;
}

.data{
    padding-top: 9%;

}

.data2{
    padding-top: 9%;

}


.data p{
    font-size: 40px;

}

/*So this is were I have started to draw the circle*/
/*All you have to do is set the width and height the same and then set the border radius to 50% and you have yourself circle*/

/* The circle */
.ec-circle{
    width: 420px;
    height: 420px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 210px;
    -moz-border-radius: 210px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family:'Kelly Slab', Georgia, serif;
    background: #DCF8C6 ;
    -webkit-box-shadow:
        inset 0 0 1px 230px rgb(20, 189, 149), inset 0 0 0 7px #14BD95;
    -moz-box-shadow:
          inset 0 0 1px 230px rgb(20, 189, 149), inset 0 0 0 7px #14BD95;
    box-shadow:
      inset 0 0 1px 230px rgb(20, 189, 149), inset 0 0 0 7px #14BD95;
    -webkit-transition: box-shadow 400ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: box-shadow 400ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: box-shadow 400ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: box-shadow 400ms ease-in-out;
    transition: box-shadow 400ms ease-in-out;
    /*For IE < 9 so that we have some kind of effect */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
    display: block;
    outline: none;
}
.ec-circle-hover{

    -webkit-box-shadow:
          inset 0 0 0 0 rgb(20, 189, 149), inset 0 0 0 5px #14BD95,
        0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow:
        inset 0 0 0 0 rgb(20, 189, 149), inset 0 0 0 5px #14BD95,
        0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow:
        inset 0 0 0 0 rgb(20, 189, 149), inset 0 0 0 5px #14BD95,
        0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    /*For IE < 9 so that we have some kind of effect */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
}

h1{
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
}
.circle{
padding-top: 3%;

}

/* Text inside of circle */
.ec-circle h3{
    color: transparent;
    font-size: 27px;
        margin-top: 4%;
    line-height: 10px;


}




.ec-circle-hover h3{
    color: white;
    transition:all 1s ease;
-webkit-transition-delay:all 100ms ease-in-out;
-moz-transition-delay:all 100ms ease-in-out;
-ms-transition-delay:all 100ms ease-in-out;
-o-transition-delay:all 100ms ease-in-out;


}

.ec-circle-hover .h3c{
    color: black;
    border-bottom: 1px;
    border-color: red;
}


/* The circle */
.ec-circle2{
    width: 220px;
    height: 220px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 210px;
    -moz-border-radius: 210px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family:'Kelly Slab', Georgia, serif;
    background: #DCF8C6 ;
    -webkit-box-shadow:
        inset 0 0 1px 230px rgb(20, 189, 149), inset 0 0 0 7px #14BD95;
    -moz-box-shadow:
          inset 0 0 1px 230px rgb(20, 189, 149), inset 0 0 0 7px #14BD95;
    box-shadow:
      inset 0 0 1px 230px rgb(20, 189, 149), inset 0 0 0 7px #14BD95;
    -webkit-transition: box-shadow 400ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: box-shadow 400ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: box-shadow 400ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: box-shadow 400ms ease-in-out;
    transition: box-shadow 400ms ease-in-out;
    /*For IE < 9 so that we have some kind of effect */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
    display: block;
    outline: none;
}
.ec-circle2-hover{

    -webkit-box-shadow:
          inset 0 0 0 0 rgb(20, 189, 149), inset 0 0 0 5px #14BD95,
        0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow:
        inset 0 0 0 0 rgb(20, 189, 149), inset 0 0 0 5px #14BD95,
        0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow:
        inset 0 0 0 0 rgb(20, 189, 149), inset 0 0 0 5px #14BD95,
        0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    /*For IE < 9 so that we have some kind of effect */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
}

h1{
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
}
.circle{
padding-top: 3%;

}

/* Text inside of circle */
.ec-circle2 h3{
    color: transparent;
    font-size: 27px;
        margin-top: 4%;
    line-height: 10px;


}




.ec-circle2-hover h3{
    color: white;
    transition:all 1s ease;
-webkit-transition-delay:all 100ms ease-in-out;
-moz-transition-delay:all 100ms ease-in-out;
-ms-transition-delay:all 100ms ease-in-out;
-o-transition-delay:all 100ms ease-in-out;


}

.ec-circle2-hover .h3c2{
    color: black;
    border-bottom: 1px;
    border-color: red;
}
```

And the html/ JavaScript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Hover and Click Trigger for Circular Elements with jQuery</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kelly+Slab' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.custom.72835.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">

            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="section">
                    <div class="normal-trigger-area">
                        <div id="circle" class="ec-circle">
                            <div class="data"><p>Kati</p>
                <h3 class="h3c">Size</h3>
                  <h3>- 2023 -</h3>
                <h3 class="h3c">Habitat</h3>
                  <h3>- Mostly forest -</h3>
                  <h3 class="h3c">Number of Takahe Pairs</h3>
                <h3> - 10 -</h3></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.circlemouse.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {

        $('#circle').circlemouse({
          onMouseEnter  : function( el ) {

            el.addClass('ec-circle-hover');

          },
          onMouseLeave  : function( el ) {

            el.removeClass('ec-circle-hover');

          },

        });

      });
        </script>

        <div class="container">

            <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="section">
          <div class="normal-trigger-area">
            <div id="circle2" class="ec-circle2">
              <div class="data2"><p>Kati</p>
                <h3 class="h3c2">Size</h3>
                  <h3>- 2023 -</h3>
                <h3 class="h3c2">Habitat</h3>
                  <h3>- Mostly forest -</h3>
                  <h3 class="h3c2">Number of Takahe Pairs</h3>
                <h3> - 10 -</h3></div>
            </div>
          </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.circlemouse.js"></script>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {

        $('#circle2').circlemouse({
          onMouseEnter  : function( el ) {

            el.addClass('ec-circle-hover2');

          },
          onMouseLeave  : function( el ) {

            el.removeClass('ec-circle-hover2');

          },

        });

      });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: First thing first - code should be **in the question** and not an external page. Second, I don't think you need to apply `ec-circle-hover2` on hovering second circle. Same class can be applied to multiple elements and so you can apply `ec-circle-hover` itself, Plus I don't see any `ec-circle-hover2` in your CSS.

Comment: @Jaromanda X Haha well I need some ointment for that burn lol ;)

Comment: @Harry You are correct and I realised that as soon as I posted it, my bad. You just committed really fast lol. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your css have no class defined name ".ec-circle-hover2"

And while you hover you can adding class name above same

So please define that class(ec-circle-hover2) in css and then run your code

Answer (score 3):

Change

`el.addClass('ec-circle-hover2');`

To

```
el.addClass('ec-circle2-hover');
```

Same with removeClass also.

Answer (score 3):

First you will check ur id's and class name.
After that you will ask Questions.

Comment: Yea my bad next time I will do that. Thanks for the advise  :)